# center upper div

Tags: html, center

I am trying to center my navigation in a pure CSS page.
I am going for the 'everything centered' look.

Currently, I have 3 div side by side. Is this the best route?
Or should I use 1 div and try to center that?

How can I achieve this?
Help would be appreciated!

Here is my page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="navigation.js"></script>
    </head><body>


<div id="top">



<header>
    <div id="topLeft"></div>
    <nav id="nav-wrap">

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Attendees</a><ul><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li></ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Exhibitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Speakers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Program</a></li>

    </ul>

</nav>
<div id="topRight">topright</div>
</header>

</div>  

<div id="middle">
<div id="headerLeft"></div>
<div id="headerimage">
    <img src="header-2013.jpg"/>
    </div>

<div id="headerRight"></div>    
    <br style="clear: left;" />

</div>

<div id="pagewrap"> 











<div id="content">
            <!--  <h3>To see the mobile navigation, narrow your browser window or check with a mobile device.</h3>
        <p>Unholy is a new, upcoming raiding guild with goals of
successfully accomplishing Player versus Environment and Player versus Player
raiding content. If thou art seeking such guild then thou would consider joining
us on our quest to victory over the evils that lurk within the depths of
Karazhan and Zul'Aman. All are welcome that have experienced the foul beasts
that roam abroad the forsaken ground in the Outlands and whish to further
explore and cleanse such places. If this should be thy calling then we welcome
you to our quest for victory, For the Horde </p> -->
        </div>






</div>

<footer>
<div id="footer">
footer
</div>
</footer>
</body></html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/************************************************************************************
GENERAL
*************************************************************************************/
html {
    height: auto;
}

body {
    font: .9em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /******extra Mike Clayton **/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #39C;
}

h1,h2 {
    line-height: 120%;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #000;
}

header {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

/************************************************************************************
STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/
#pagewrap {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    /**Mike Clayton**/
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    clear: both;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    /**Mike clayton**/
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;

    padding-bottom:300px;
}

#top {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #002664;
    clear: both;
}

#topLeft {
    float: left;
    background-color: #002664;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left:200px;
}

#topRight {
    float: left;
    background-color: #002664;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
}

#middle {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #AD1B30;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#headerLeft {
    float: left;
    background-color: #AD1B30;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
}

#headerimage {
    width: 650px;
    align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerimage img {
    width: 100%;
}

#headerRight {
    float: left;
    background-color: #AD1B30;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #002664;
    width: 100%;
}
/************************************************************************************
NAV
*************************************************************************************/
#nav-wrap {
    margin-top: 20px;


}

/* menu icon */
#menu-icon {
    display: none; /* hide menu icon initially */
}

#nav,#nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

/* nav link */
#nav a {
    padding: 4px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    background: #ecebeb;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

/* nav dropdown */
#nav ul {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    display: none; /* hide dropdown */
    width: 200px;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li:hover>ul {
    display: block; /* show dropdown on hover */
}

/************************************************************************************
MOBILE
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* nav-wrap */
    #nav-wrap {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* menu icon */
    #menu-icon {
        color: #000;
        width: 42px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #ecebeb url(menu-icon.png) no-repeat 10px center;
        padding: 8px 10px 0 42px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: solid 1px #666;
        display: block; /* show menu icon */
    }
    #menu-icon:hover {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    #menu-icon.active {
        background-color: #bbb;
    }

    /* main nav */
    #nav {
        clear: both;
        position: absolute;
        top: 38px;
        width: 160px;
        z-index: 10000;
        padding: 5px;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        border: solid 1px #999;
        display: none; /* visibility will be toggled with jquery */
    }
    #nav li {
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    }
    #nav a,#nav ul a {
        font: inherit;
        background: none;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0;
        color: #666;
        border: none;
    }
    #nav a:hover,#nav ul a:hover {
        background: none;
        color: #000;
    }

    /* dropdown */
    #nav ul {
        width: auto;
        position: static;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        background: inherit;
    }
    #nav ul li {
        margin: 3px 0 3px 15px;
    }
    #headerimage {
        display: none;
    }

    /**Mike Clayton**/
    #footer {
        clear: both;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        height: 3em;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #002664;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* ensure #nav is visible on desktop version */
    #nav {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your navwrap:

```
 #nav-wrap {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 20px;
 left: 100%;
 }
```

You can also use px values instead of percentages.

Good luck!

Comment: that definitely helps to center it, but there is a problem. When I re-size the browser everything shifts/re-sizes properly, but the navigation stays fixed. I want everything in the middle and move together when the browser is re-sized.

Comment: I was able center everything, as well as centered when the window is re-sized. I did this by centering the <header> html 5 element.